# How to use Neo4j variables, behaviour of query different without using the variables/identifier

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4J, the "CREATE" queries are like

`create (n: Object {name:"abcd"})`
where "n" is identifier.

I wish to understand, how to utilise this identifier, and is it mandatory to have it ?

I did a little experiment, I used the query.

`create (Object {name: "xyz"})`

But, when I do query all the nodes with label "Object" , this node with name "xyz" do not shows up.

`match(n:Object) return n`

And it shows up in the global node table, which is strange.

[image: Node created without Identifier and label "Object"]
[image: Node created with Identifier and label "Object"]
[image: Result of Nodes for label "Object", xyz node is not there]
[image: Xyz node gets displayed in Global nodes without "Object" label]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a label to nodes, the ":" is mandatory. It means these two statements are equivalents:

```
CREATE (n:Object {name:"abcd"})
```

and

```
CREATE (:Object {name:"abcd"})
```

However when you write:

```
CREATE (Object {name:"abcd"})
```

the identifier becomes "Object" and the later node is created without any label. That's also what Neo4j tells you: "Created 1 node, set 1 property". While in the first scenario (with the ":"), it also tells you it has added 1 label).

Regarding the identifier "n", it is not mandatory. It is only intended to refer to that node later in the query, for instance to create a relationship:

```
CREATE (n:Object {name:"abcd"})
CREATE (m:Object {name:"efgh"})
CREATE (n)-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(m)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it explains what I sought.